# Ansible - correct way for privilege elevation

Tags: ansible, sudo, package-managers

I am writing a playbook in order to install a package from portage:

```
---
- hosts: '1.2.3.4'
  sudo: True
  become_user: admin_x
- tasks:
    - name: "install nspr"
      portage: package=dev-libs/nspr state=present
```

This fails, telling me I do not not have sudo permissions:

`ansible-playbook foo.yml --limit 1.2.3.4 -k --ask-sudo-pass`

I have seen that you should use become, but the documentation for that is [pretty much a gap](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html). Could someone give me an example how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

deploy.yml:

```
- name: Todo something
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: su
```

When you execute the playbook pass the password like a extra var.

```
--extra-vars='ansible_become_pass=password'
```